# Can I Use a Delegate Variable in a Join and Get an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, delegates

### Origin

I have a LINQ-to-SQL query that will vary slightly based on external criteria. I wrote a switch statement for the three different cases, but the series of queries in the different cases are nearly identical. The only thing that differs is the delegate used for the join condition.

So, in order to make my code DRYer, I decided to just use the switch statement to select from three different delegates. I would then save the chosen delagate in a variable, and use that variable in the .Join call.

### Problem

However, when I use the variable instead of explicitly typing out the delegate, the .Join no longer returns an IQueryable but instead returns an IEnumerable. I should clarify that I'm getting the return value from Intellisense on the 'var' keyword.

So this one returns an IQueryable:

```
var dc = new CloudDataContext();
var manifests = dc.ShippingManifests.Join(
    dc.Locations,
    man => man.OriginId,
    loc => loc.Id,
    (man, loc) => man
);
```

But this one returns an IEnumerable:

```
protected static int? ManifestOriginId( ShippingManifest manifest ) {
    return manifest.OriginId;
}

Func<ShippingManifest, int?> originJoiner = GridModelManifests.ManifestOriginId;

var dc = new CloudDataContext();
var manifests = dc.ShippingManifests.Join(
    dc.Locations,
    originJoiner,
    loc => loc.Id,
    (man, loc) => man
);
```

### Question

I'm curious why this happens, but I'm more curious how I can accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to get an IQueryable, as the resulting query is going to be passed on down the line for further manipulation.

Comment: I'm curious, what happens when you do this: `Func<ShippingManifest, int?> originJoiner = (man) => man.OriginId;`? I think its the hydration of your lambda prematurely that's causing your issue.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Nope, same thing. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Ohhh..  sorry. It's Linq to SQL.. it will be expecting an `Expresion<Func<ShippingManifest, int?>>`. That is so it can convert the expression tree to a SQL query thereby allowing an `IQueryable` to be returned. If its not an `Expression`, it will break that and hydrate your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as an `Expression`.

When it isn't, the query will probably be hydrated and pulled into memory prior to the join. What you're after is an `Expression<Func<ShippingManifest, int?>>`:

```
Expression<Func<ShippingManifest, int?>> originJoiner = man => man.OriginId;
```

This allows the expression visitor in Linq to SQL to continue processing it before it sends it off to the database.

Comment: No problem at all. Sorry my first comment was useless - had a bit of a brain fart I think! :)